# Why is cherry matched and not matched?

Tags: python, pandas, contains

The string `"Cherry/berry"` is searched for the string `"cherry"` and I would have thought that using `re.IGNORECASE` or `str.lower()` would give the same result, but it does not, why?

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {"description": ["Cherry/berry"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


is_contained = df["description"].str.contains(r"\b(cherry)\b", re.IGNORECASE)
print(is_contained[0]) # False

is_contained = df["description"].str.lower().str.contains(r"\b(cherry)\b")
print(is_contained[0]) # True
```

Comment: The second parameter to [`contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) is `case`, which when non-zero (as is `re.IGNORECASE`) causes the match to be case-sensitive. Just use `str.contains(r"\b(cherry)\b", False` instead.

Comment: Note you don't need a capture group `()` in your regex.

Comment: `df["description"].str.contains(r"\b(cherry)\b", flags=re.IGNORECASE)` will be `True`.

Comment: As an aside, you can also put the modifiers directly into the pattern: `r"(?i)\bcherry\b"`

Answer (score 5):

As explained in the comments, you should not pass regex flags to the `case` parameter of [`contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df["description"].str.contains(r"\b(cherry)\b", case=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Instead you would need to use the **`flags`** parameter:

```
df["description"].str.contains(r"\b(cherry)\b", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Or use the `case` parameter:

```
df["description"].str.contains(r"\b(cherry)\b", case=False)
```

Output:

```
0    True
Name: description, dtype: bool
```

##### why did it fail?

regex flags are nothing but integers (`re.IGNORECASE` is actually `2`). When passed to the case parameter (which expects a boolean), you are in fact running:

```
df["description"].str.contains(r"\b(cherry)\b", case=bool(2))

# or
df["description"].str.contains(r"\b(cherry)\b", case=True)
```